# cholmod long version functions return null pointer — c programming

Tags: c, long-integer, sparse-matrix, null-pointer, suitesparse

I am using SuiteSparse @4.2.1_3 installed via macports and want to allocate a cholmod_dense structure. 
Consider the following piece of code:

```
/* start CHOLMOD */
cholmod_common c;
cholmod_dense* myv;
cholmod_dense* myv2;

cholmod_start (&c);
myv  = cholmod_l_allocate_dense( 4,1,4,CHOLMOD_REAL,&c);
myv2 = cholmod_allocate_dense(4,1,4,CHOLMOD_REAL,&c);
printf("myv=%p\n",myv);
printf("myv2=%p\n",myv2);

/* finish CHOLMOD */
cholmod_finish (&c) ;
```

I get the following output:

```
myv=0x0
myv2=0x7fb86ac0c060
```

That means allocate `cholmod_dense` structure in long version does not work but integer version works well.
Does anyone know a reason why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct itype in the `cholmod_common` structure `c`.

```
c.itype=CHOLMOD_LONG;

/* Common->itype and Common->dtype are used to define the types of all
 * sparse matrices, triplet matrices, dense matrices, and factors
 * created using this Common struct.  The itypes and dtypes of all
 * parameters to all CHOLMOD routines must match.  */
```